Character of a power $\chi_{\rho}(g^k)$ for $SU(N)$
Probably a silly question on representation theory from physicist. I need to express characters of the form $\chi_{\rho}(g^k)$ where $g\in SU(N)$ (or other continuous groups) in terms of characters $\chi_{\rho}(g)$. Is there some way to do it in general?
For the case of $\rho$ being fundamental representation as far as I understand it is enough to use Newton's identities for power sums in order to derive what I want using symmetric polynomials. But for example in case of $\rho$ being adjoint representation I do not know the answer.
UPD: After searching a bit deeper I found out that the proper name for what I need is Adams operation. It is enough for my purpose since it is implemented in SageMath where I write my code. However if anyone can tell me if closed form expressions for $SU(N)$ beyond fundamental representation are derivable and exist I would be very happy to have  a link/clue for derivation.

In general, the irreducible representations of $SU(N)$ are parameterized by partitions $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{n-1})$ and the corresponding characters are just Schur polynomials $s_{\lambda}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ (here $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is the spectrum of a given element). Then, you essentially want to decompose $s_{\lambda}(x_1^k,\ldots,x_n^k)$ into linear combination of Schur polynomials. I am not sure whether the exact formulas exist, but this procedure is related to plethysm (or composition). Perhaps, you can start by first looking at examples in Macdonald's book.

Namely, in I. G. Macdonald, Symmetric functions and Hall polynomials, Chapter I, $\S 8$.

@richrow  Thanks for the comment. In fact that is how I derived what I need for the fundamental representation, just experimentally finding what is the right expansion of $s_{[1,0,0...]}(x_1^k,...,x_n^k)$ in terms of $s_{\lambda}(x_1^k,...,x_n^k)$. But in fundamental representation it is simple enough to do because Schur polynomial is just powersum $p_1$. I am also familiar with the Macdonald book well enough but did not find the answer there. Though maybe I should look better.
